# Tips for brewing stations in the Nether

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As far as I know at this stage it is impossible to get water into the Nether. I know it could be done in previous versions with silk touch and ice, but that is over now. And in the new versions silk touch will work on ice, but breaking ice in the Nether will not give you water.

So I am looking for a good setup so I can make some potions in the Nether, mostly instant health, splash damage, and speed potions.

One solution I often read is bringing filled water bottles into the Nether, but that is just a 1-1 solution, I do not like that too much.

I was thinking of the following setup. I fill a chest in the Nether with water buckets, and one chest with stacks of all the ingredients I need. Than in the brewing station I have a cauldron. Now if I understand correctly with a filled cauldron you can fill 3 bottles.

So now I can bring buckets of water instead of bottles, so 1 inventory space will give me 3 potions.

One thing also is that when you go back you can fill all the buckets with lava.

---

Will this be a good setup, or are there more efficient ways to create your brewing station in the Nether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 5 hours, when 1.3 is out, I guess you could fill an ender chest with water buckets when you're in the overworld. Place another ender chest close to your brewing stand and you're all set.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how you play minecraft. The tricky thing about brewing potions isn't just that you can't really produce water in the nether, it's that your netherwort will NOT GROW unless you're in the nether (and the chunk it's planted in is loaded). That my friend, is the issue.

You have two solutions in my eyes.

- You can do what your already doing with buckets and cauldrons (this is what I do). But to further make your life easier, you can build a portal very near your brewing station. (build the portal on the nether side) Go through the portal (you should now be in the real world) and dig a hole 1 block deep, 2 blocks wide and 2 blocks long. Put a water source in each opposite corner of the hole and you will have an endless watering hole to easily fill your buckets back up and jump right through the portal back to your station.
- You can do all your brewing in the real world (nothing is stopping you) - The only problem is your going to have to find some reason to spend time in the nether to let your netherwort grow. I suggest you build an underground chamber in the Nether, plant a LOT of netherwort, and spend a few hours or so building something cool, or killing zombie pigman, or doing both maybe. If you grow enough netherwort, such as a room of it 20blocks x 20 blocks, That will likely be more than enough to last you several weeks. The stuff lasts quite some time, unless of course you drink your potions like candy.

Comment: Netherwort will be able to grow in the overworld and the end in 1.3 (the change was first added in 12w27a)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do spend a decent amount of time in the Nether, that is why I want to have a brewing station there. I had a blaze farm, and now I am building a new dual blaze farm. In the single blaze farm it always annoyed me to stand there and punch all the blaze. So now in the dual blaze farm I want to use potions instead. While the collection area fills up I want to spend the time brewing. I have a reasonable amount of blocks I can walk around and both spawners are still enabled. So I guess water buckets will be the best way to go?

Comment: @StevenCunningham Nice that they will grow in the overworld. I do spend a lot of time in the Nether so that was not really an issue. But with this you can make some nice looking farms in the overworld, and use water to flush them down finally.

Comment: @SaifBechan If your going to be spending that much time in the nether, then yes, water buckets would be best.